# echo command displaying INT or DATE fields

Tags: php, echo

Here is some sample code, which I need help with. The usercode works, as its a VARCHAR. The weeknumber is blank, as its an INT. Same problem with a date field.

How can I get these to display a value ?

```
for($i=0; $i<$nrows; $i++)
    {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $x = (int) $row['year'];
            echo "<tr>";    
            echo "<td>". $row['usercode'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['weeknumber'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: How are you inserting these into the database?

Comment: Please make sure `weeknumber` actually contains any number, because it should display fine as it is.

Comment: sounds like you are not pulling these fields. What is your SQL query? / Are you sure the data is in the database?

Comment: Yes, the field is being pulled, as "usercode" is being displayed nicely. The other fields, such as weeknumber, is showing on the page as blank, even though it does contain data. The same applies to a date field, which I didn't put in the sample above